# Conditional column formatting for cells with values

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I need to create conditional cell formatting but only for rows that will not be blank. This Excel file will be used as a template that Python script will fill with data so if there are rows without data, these rows should not be formatted.

As per illustration below, I need to create a formula that will apply conditional formatting for banded columns in two colors- light grey and white.

Is there a better way to implement this rather than creating conditional formatting rule for each cell individually?

Tried this and tested conditions, but no formatting is being done.

[image]

Comment: How about using `ISBLANK`, `MOD` and `COLUMN`?

Comment: @BigBen, I tried AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B12)); MOD(COLUMN(); 1)=0) but it does not seem to change formatting when I enter value in a cell within the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ISBLANK`, `MOD`, and `COLUMN`:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),MOD(COLUMN(A2),2)=1)
```

[image]

Change the formula separator to `;` as necessary, and ensure the *Applies to* range begins in `A2`, or whichever cell corresponds to the first row.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, your solution should be working. Not sure why my Excel is not formatting cells even though I tested conditions in cells and they are correct.

Comment: I figured out why my formula did not work. For some reason it was being surrounded with double quotation every time I would edit it.